# javascript replace first array value with second array value. First array length is 2 and second one length is 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, arraylist, mapreduce

I have two arrays a and b and i need to replace array b value with a.

```
a= [1,2];
b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

Expected output should be like this

```
[1,2,1,2,1,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the index of the target array and map the value of source array with the index and remainder operator for the given length.

```js
var a = [1, 2],
    b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    
b = b.map((_, i) => a[i % a.length]);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
var output = b.map( function(item, index){
  return a[ index % a.length ]
});
```

**Demo**

```js
var a= [1,2];
var b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

var output = b.map( function(item, index){
  return a[ index % a.length ]
});

console.log( JSON.stringify( output ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach to change the array in place and modulo to get the right index. You also can use map on the array if you want a new one.

```js
var a = [1,2]
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var l = a.length
b.forEach((el,idx,arr) => {
  arr[idx] = a[idx%l]
})

console.log(b)
```